# Google maps do not show up in Ionic2 app

Tags: google-maps, angular, ionic2

The problem is that I don't see any map and the error appears when subscribe runs. Does anyone know how to help me?
I tryied some ways btu they don't work
[google-maps-into-ionic-2](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-maps-into-ionic-2/59456/6) or [google maps from ionic native](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-maps-from-ionic-native/54013/22)

Html:

```
<button (click)="getMapresults()"></button>
<ion-content>
   <div id="mapid"></div>
</ion-content>
```

Trypescript:

```
import {Component, ViewChild, OnInit, NgZone} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {
  Geolocation, GoogleMap, GoogleMapsEvent, GoogleMapsMarker, GoogleMapsMarkerOptions,
  CameraPosition, GoogleMapsLatLng
} from "ionic-native";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
private gMap: GoogleMap;

location: {lat: number, lng: number};

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
            public platform:Platform
) {}

getMapresults() {
   this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
      console.log('Platform ready!');
      this.gMap = new GoogleMap('mapid');

      this.gMap.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY)
      .subscribe(()=>{
        console.log('Map!');
      });

}
```

Error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.1.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
    "angular2-google-maps": "^0.16.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.45",
    "typescript": "2.0.6"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ],
  "description": "firstMobApp: An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: add `.catch(err => console.log(err))` block after `then` to see the error

Comment: "plugin_not_installed"
I get tow warning messages
`Native: tried accessing the undefined plugin but it's not installed`
`Install the undefined plugin: 'ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps'`

But cordova-plugin-googlemaps is already installed, so I don't get it

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems in your code. You need to send some parameters to Google map API in order to load google maps.

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
 import { GoogleMap, GoogleMapsEvent, GoogleMapsLatLng } from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
 selector: 'home-page',
 templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

map: GoogleMap;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.loadMap();
    });
}

loadMap(){

    let location = new GoogleMapsLatLng(-34.9290,138.6010);

    this.map = new GoogleMap('map', {
      'backgroundColor': 'white',
      'controls': {
        'compass': true,
        'myLocationButton': true,
        'indoorPicker': true,
        'zoom': true
      },
      'gestures': {
        'scroll': true,
        'tilt': true,
        'rotate': true,
        'zoom': true
      },
      'camera': {
        'latLng': location,
        'tilt': 30,
        'zoom': 15,
        'bearing': 50
      }
    });

    this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).subscribe(() => {
        console.log('Map is ready!');
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Did you add goole-maps cordova plugin ?

Comment: I did `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="xxxxxx"` (for iOs as well) and it says that these APIs are already installed

Comment: delete node_module in you ionic app. Then run npm install

Comment: I have the same issue , did you solve it yet ? @Donovant